# Truancy or Skip class

Tags: differences

At my school, I realized that most of my teachers use the phrase "skip class/school" while only a few of them use the word "truancy/truant". So, my question is what is the difference between these alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Truancy* is the formal term for it. Phrases like *skipping class/school*, *cutting class/school*, *ditching class/school*, and *playing hooky* are all informal or slang. People are more likely to use the informal phrases when they're talking casually, but in a more formal situation, such as an official record or a letter written to the student's parents, *truancy* would be the best choice.

Answer (score 1):

*Skipping class* means not going to one specific class; *truancy* is skipping school entirely.

*Ditching* or *playing hooky* on the other hand can mean either.